My motor driver does not work at high load
First of all, I apologize for my bad English. I am designing a BLDC motor driver for my university project but there are certain problems. I use IR2104 MOSFET driver integration for my motor driver. I use UF3710 as MOSFET and STM32F407VG card as PWM source. I built the circuit according to the schematic given in the IR2104 datasheet and when I connect 12 V fans separately for 3 phases, both fans work and I see PWM at the output, but when I connect a 48 V 800 W motor, it does not draw current from the power supply. Since I thought that my power supply could not draw enough current, I lowered the duty cycle value, but again there is no reaction. Am I doing something wrong?
Note: I use 10 µF capacitors in the circuit.
Note: I use 120 degree phase different PWM waves for PWM.
Note: The motor I said is a 3-phase 48 V 800 W BLDC motor. I am trying to install 3 of the circuit in the picture and connect one phase of the motor to each load part and try to run it.
Note: Vcc = 12 V
Note: I increased the voltage by switching with a transistor because the STM32 signal was insufficient, but the problem did not change.
Note: I am new to both the site and engineering, so if there is something missing, I will add it if you specify.


I get such an image in two phases

Phase 3 has such an image, could this be the reason why it does not draw current?

Show your whole circuit. You mention "three phase" and "12v fan(s)". Neither are depicted in your schematic.

I don't have a circuit schematic. I prepared 3 of the circuit in this image and connected 12 volt fans I found randomly to the load part. I did it this way because the motor I will use is 3-phase.

You have to show how you connected the 800W motor. And is the 800W motor single-phase or 3 phase? Describe the motor.

what is vcc votage?

Unanswerable without full schematic and oscillograms of nodes of interest.
